# How to get a log4net log file's name pattern programmatically?

Tags: c#, log4net

I am trying to write a C# code, which retrieves in runtime the name pattern of a *log4net* log file via the log4net API.

That is, if in *log4net.config* the following appender is defined:

```xml
<appender name="MyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\%date{dd}\%property{Id}.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="16" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I would like to get *%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\%date{dd}\%property{Id}.log* in a string variable in code (without parsing *log4net.config* as a plain XML).

Does anybody has an idea ho to pull this trick?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The value for this pattern will be in the `File` property of a `FileAppender` instance that's part of your logging repository.

Getting at the appender can be done in a couple of different ways.

1. If you already have an `ILogger` instance (e.g. what you get from `LogManager.GetLogger()`) then there's an `Appenders` property on it. This will give you any appenders associated with that specific level of the logging heirarchy.
2. You can also call `LogManager.GetRepository()` to get a `Heirarchy` object that contains the entire logger and appender heirarchy. The method expects an assembly, so pass [`GetCallingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) to get the default one. This class has a `GetAppenders()` method that returns all configured appenders, though it won't tell you which ones are associated with which loggers.

From there, just look through looking for an appender of the correct type (e.g. `FileAppender` or `RollingFileAppender`), then read it's `File` property.

Comment: I think that does not work. The file property is already evaluated at that point. So it will no longer contain `%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\%date{dd}...` but `2012\09\...`.

Comment: @Michael
Wolfgang is absolutely right: when retrieved the _File_ property was already evaluated, and I couldn't get the original pattern value.

Comment: hrm. you're right, I've always used this to just get the path (which we don't usually pattern) and never noticed. This data has to be available somewhere because the pattern is recalculated  at some point, let me dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of Michael Edenfield is good. Here's realization.

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

string fileName = ((RollingFileAppender)log.Logger.Repository.GetCurrentLoggers()
    .Where(e => e.Name == "Your namespace.class").ToList()[0]
    .Repository.GetAppenders()
    .Where(e => e.Name == "MyAppender").ToList()[0]).File.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to subclass RollingFileAppender, and use your subclass in the config file, instead of the base class.  Make sure to prefix the classname with full namespace so log4net can find it.

I have only a UDPAppender subclassed in my code.  I added an override like this:

```
    public override void ActivateOptions()
    {
        base.ActivateOptions();
    }
```

When I broke before the base class call, I examined 'this' in the locals window and saw the values for the UDPAppender 'members'.

Comment: Unfortunately, an instance of _RollingFileAppender_ is set already with the evaluated file name and is unaware of the file name pattern. I guess the last object that sees this pattern is an instance of _log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator_ in the _ParseAppender()_ method. In such case, the only way to achieve what I need is indeed parsing the config file on my own (yuck!)...

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. You want the pattern itself. I suppose that someone might change the pattern and so you don't want to set it via code (so then you would know it in advance)?

Answer (score 0):

I can obtain the value of the `<file value>` with the following code:

```
((log4net.Appender.FileAppender) ((log4net.Appender.IAppender[])
            ( (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)
                log.Logger).Appenders.SyncRoot)[0]).File
```